Android map doesn't auto zoom after calling CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(xx)
I have a fragment which displays the position of store on Google Map:
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptorFactory
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions


class AboutFragment : Fragment(), OnMapReadyCallback {


    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    }

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        val mapFragment = childFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.store_map) as SupportMapFragment?
        mapFragment?.getMapAsync(this)
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_about, container, false)
    }

    override fun onMapReady(gmap: GoogleMap) {
        val AWESOME_STORE_POSITION  = LatLng(-6.20175, 106.78208)

        val markerOptions = MarkerOptions().position(AWESOME_STORE_POSITION ).title("Awesome Store").icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.ic_location))
        gmap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(AWESOME_STORE_POSITION ))
        gmap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(AWESOME_STORE_POSITION , 5f))
        gmap.addMarker(markerOptions)


    }
}

val AWESOME_STORE_POSITION = LatLng(-6.20175, 106.78208) is a real position. Google Map shows it's an area on West Jakarta, Indonesia. Running the app gives this result:

Initially, Google Map shows Africa. So I have to pinch and zoom a few times till reaching West Jakarta, but the marker isn't there. What's wrong here? Isn't gmap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(20f)) suppose to auto zoom the map to the marker?
I'm using com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:18.2.0

Can you debug and tell us onMapReady is getting triggered or not.

@BobSmith finally found the culprint. The Google Map initialisation stuffs should be  done inside onViewCreated() instead of onCreateView(). Then it works fine.

Good to see you solved the problem by yourself :) consider posting and accepting it as correct answer

OnMapReady is never called
val mapFragment = childFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.jollycat_map) as SupportMapFragment?

here you are trying to cast mapFragment to a type of SupportMapFragment or null.
since the cast doesn't succeed the next line
 mapFragment?.getMapAsync(this)

doesn't call getMapAsync. Since you are using a safe call,
you don't get an error.
Now for the reason the cast is not successful,
it's simply because you are calling the fragment with the wrong ID.
val mapFragment = childFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.store_map) as SupportMapFragment?
    mapFragment?.getMapAsync(this)

should work.
You can read more about Kotlin type-checks here.

Ah sorry for the store_map typo. Seems like the ? cast is necessary. Removing it like this: val mapFragment = childFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.store_map) as SupportMapFragment mapFragment.getMapAsync(this)
causes this error: java.lang.NullPointerException: null cannot be cast to non-null type com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment Perhaps I need to downgrade the play service map lib?

it's indeed necessary but it means you have to address the fact that the mapFragment might be null. You can try using parentFragmentManager instead of the child one.
